If Rational function $R(u,v)=R(-u,v)$, then $R(u,v)=R_1(u^2,v)$
In my textbook Zorich's Mathematical Analysis, this question had been proposed as the first in the second problem:

And I got immediately stuck with the first part of the problem.
I have tried to make the substitution of  $R(u,v)$ to this:
$$R(u,v)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n u^{\alpha_i} v^{\beta_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n u^{\gamma_j}v^{\lambda_j}}$$
And I substituted $R(u,v)=R(-u,v)$, but my attempt did not succeed in proving the result.

Related.

If $S(u,v)$ is a polynomial then it can be represented as $\sum_{k,l} a_{k,l}u^kv^l.$ The condition $S(u,v)=S(-u,v)$ implies
$$S(u,v)={1\over 2}[S(u,v)+S(-u,v)]\\ ={1\over 2}\sum_{k,l} [a_{k,l}+(-1)^ka_{k,l}]u^kv^l 
=\sum_{k,l\atop k-{\rm even}}a_{k,l}u^kv^l$$ Thus $S(u,v)=\tilde{S}(u^2,v)$ for a polynomial $\tilde{S}.$
For a rational function $R=P/Q,$
if $R(-u,v)=R(u,v),$ then
$$R(u,v)={1\over 2}\left ({P(u,v)\over Q(u,v)}+{P(-u,v)\over Q(-u,v)} \right ) \\= {P(u,v)Q(-u,v)+P(-u,v)Q(u,v)\over 2Q(-u,v)Q(u,v)}$$ The polynomials in the numerator and the denominator are even with respect to $u$ thus they are of the form $\tilde{P}(u^2,v)$ and $\tilde{Q}(u^2,v),$ respectively, by the first part.

Let's come at this in greater generality: Suppose the domain of $P$ is symmetric under some involution of variables, so can be decomposed into a sum of an even function $P_{0}$ and an odd function $P_{1}$, and similarly $Q = Q_{0} + Q_{1}$ with $Q_{0}$ even and $Q_{1}$ odd. (To emphasize, I'm using the terms even and odd more generally than is customary: Under some involution of the variables, $P_{0}$ and $Q_{0}$ are invariant, while $P_{1}$ and $Q_{1}$ change sign. Throughout, I'll also ignore formal division by $0$, which is certainly safe for analytic functions including polynomials.)
To say $R = P/Q$ satisfies $R(-u, v) = R(u, v)$ is to say
$$
\frac{P_{0} + P_{1}}{Q_{0} + Q_{1}} = \frac{P_{0} - P_{1}}{Q_{0} - Q_{1}}.
$$
In detail,
\begin{align*}
  \frac{P_{0}(u, v) + P_{1}(u, v)}{Q_{0}(u, v) + Q_{1}(u, v)}
  &= R(u, v) \\
  &= R(-u, v) \\
  &= \frac{P_{0}(-u, v) + P_{1}(-u, v)}{Q_{0}(-u, v) + Q_{1}(-u, v)} \\
  &= \frac{P_{0}(u, v) - P_{1}(u, v)}{Q_{0}(u, v) - Q_{1}(u, v)}.
\end{align*}
Cross-multiplying and canceling terms gives the equivalent condition $-P_{0}Q_{1} + P_{1}Q_{0} = 0$, or
$$
\frac{P_{0}}{Q_{0}} = \frac{P_{1}}{Q_{1}}.
$$
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
  R &= \frac{P}{Q} \\
  &= \frac{P_{0} + P_{1}}{Q_{0} + Q_{1}} \\
  &= \frac{Q_{1}(P_{0} + P_{1})}{Q_{1}(Q_{0} + Q_{1})} \\
  &= \frac{P_{1}(Q_{0} + Q_{1})}{Q_{1}(Q_{0} + Q_{1})} \\
  &= \frac{P_{1}}{Q_{1}} \\
  &= \frac{P_{0}}{Q_{0}}.
\end{align*}
<>
To obtain the stated conclusion, it's enough to note that a polynomial $p(u, v)$ is even in $u$ if and only if it has the form $p(u, v) = \bar{p}(u^{2}, v)$ for some polynomial $\bar{p}$; and is odd in $u$ if and only if it has the form $p(u, v) = u\bar{p}(u^{2}, v)$ for some polynomial $\bar{p}$.

Small caution: My indexing is not necessarily compatible with the indexing in the problem statement. <> The larger point is, completely expanding $P$ and $Q$ in powers is less helpful than expanding only enough to express "even" and "odd" symmetries.

Forget the second variable for now since it is irrelevant to the first question.
Notice that if $u \geq 0$, then $u = \sqrt{u^2}$, and similarly, if $u\leq 0$, then $u = -\sqrt{u^2}$. Thus, ANY function $R(u)$ will be equal to $R(\sqrt{u^2})$ if $u \geq 0$ , and equal to $R(-\sqrt{u^2})$ if $u \leq 0$.
Now for your function, $R(x) = R(-x)$ for any $x$, so $R(-\sqrt{u^2}) = R(\sqrt{u^2})$ when $u \leq 0$, so that $R(u) = R(\sqrt{u^2})$ for $\textit{all}$ $u$, and you can now let $R_1(x) = R\circ\sqrt{x}$ (here $\circ$ is function composition).
In fact, $u^2$ isn't particularly special, any even function $f$ that is bijective on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ will work, by taking $R_1(x) = R \circ f^{-1}(x)$.
